# Understanding working of enctype = multipart/form-data in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

In book "Spring in Action" i read , *the default content type of a post submission is application/x-www-form-urlencoded and takes the form of name-value pairs separated by ampersands.* (I believe these all goes as the body payload of the HTTP POST request.)

I further read, *with enctype set to multipart/form-data, each field will be submitted as a distinct part of the POST request and not as just another name-value pair.*

***Q1>*** I don't get this line. I am from a REST background and will want to understand what  in content of the HTTP POST request has changed ?

The server side code

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSpitterFromForm(@Valid Spitter spitter,
    BindingResult bindingResult,
    @RequestParam(value="image", required=false)
Accept file upload
￼￼      MultipartFile image) {
if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
  return "spitters/edit";
}
spitterService.saveSpitter(spitter);
try {
  if(!image.isEmpty()) {
    validateImage(image);
Validate image
￼      saveImage(spitter.getId() + ".jpg", image); //
    }
  } catch (ImageUploadException e) {
    bindingResult.reject(e.getMessage());
    return "spitters/edit";
}
  return "redirect:/spitters/" + spitter.getUsername();
}
```

The client side code

```
    <sf:form method="POST"
                     modelAttribute="spitter"
                     enctype="multipart/form-data">
//other stuff
     <tr>
         <th><sf:label path="fullName">Full name:</sf:label></th>
         <td><sf:input path="fullName" size="15" /><br/>
             <sf:errors path="fullName" cssClass="error" />
         </td>
     </tr><tr>
      <th><label for="image">Profile image:</label></th>
      <td><input name="image" type="file"/>
    </tr>
//other stuff
    </sf:form>
```

From the code I am tempted to think that only the input type="file" is sent in a new way. Rest all are sent as key-value pairs. I think the book is also saying the same "*When the form is submitted, it’ll be posted as a multipart form where one of the parts contains the image file’s binary data.* "

***Q2>*** If what i am thinking is correct, how does client know which input types to send as key-value pairs and whom to send individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, enctype of multipart/form-data **IS NOT** a Spring-MVC thing, it is an attribute of `<form>` in general web development, which means this attribute can be present in your HTML form regardless the server side technology. You can read more about it here: [HTML 5 Candidate Recommendation [Specification] 4 The elements of HTML 4.10 Forms 4.10.22 Form submission 4.10.22.7 Multipart form data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data), also you can read specifically how the data will be sent by reading [RFC2388](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388). If you review it, you will see that data sent in a POST request with multipart/form-data is not a key/value pair anymore, instead it contains multiple parts (yes, it is multi part) where each part looks like this (example belongs to RFC2388):

```
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"
content-type: text/plain;charset=windows-1250
content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable
Joe owes =80100.
--AaB03x
```

Note that `Joe owes =80100.` means `Joe owes €100`.

You can find another example in [HTML 4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) where it shows a more concrete example when uploading two or more files (my comments are posted after `<--`):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x <-- mark for the whole request

--AaB03x <-- content of a part
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit-name" <-- field name

Larry <-- content of the field
--AaB03x <-- content of a part
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files"
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=BbC04y

--BbC04y <-- content of a part containing a file
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--BbC04y <-- content of a part containing a file
Content-Disposition: file; filename="file2.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

...contents of file2.gif...
--BbC04y-- <-- end of parts containing file
--AaB03x-- <-- end of whole request data
```

Comment: Thanks Luiggi, it just the same as multipart/mixed mime messages with various part boundaries. Just one more thing just for curiosity, can i extract submit-name like @RequestParam(value="submit-name", required=true) MultipartFile name)

Comment: Also while using multipart-formdata, how does everything else maps automatically to "spitter"